# Gender of words ending in -si

Tags: grammar, gender

I was taught that all Italian words ending in -si are femminile. But dictionaries show that 'brindisi' is maschile. Is it exception or the rule about '-si words' is wrong?

Comment: At least the reflexive form of infinitive is another exception. You say "A volte è brutto guardarsi allo specchio".

Comment: Names like *analisi, sintesi, cosmesi* are of Greek origin and feminine; actually I can't recall any other name ending in *-si* that's masculine apart from *brindisi*. I don't think that learning names' gender by “rules and exceptions” is a good strategy, but it's personal opinion.

Comment: And welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @egreg Grazie! I'm learning Italian only a month, so rules make it easier to remember for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with egreg that one should get a sense of words' gender by using them rather than with “rules and exceptions” (as an Italian I never heard explicitly that rule), by doing an advanced search on Zingarelli 2018 Italian dictionary for masculine nouns in “-si”, I find that there are only:

- *brindisi*;
- *cremisi* (crimson colour);
- *passi* (a pass);
- the musical note *si*;
- some local, rare words such as *sussi* and *biribissi*;
- some words of foreign origin such as *farsi* (the Persian language), *lassi* (an Indian drink made of yogurt), *parsi* and *tutsi* (each, a person of the respective ethnic group);
- several compound words such as *contapassi*, *schiacciasassi*, *saltafossi* and so on, where the *-si* ending comes actually from a masculine plural (*passi*, *sassi* etc.);
- some reflexive verbs in the infinitive form, used as nouns (as remarked in a comment), such as *manifestarsi* and *volgersi*.

All in all, less than 60 items are returned, including “false positives” (such as the plural name *Rapidoglossi* – a group of molluscs – or nouns with an accent, such as *sì* and *tassì*). For reference, a search for feminine nouns in “-si” returns (false positives and all) 1081 terms, from *abiogenesi* to *zooprofilassi*.

So, in a large majority of cases, I'd say that the rule you have been taught can be considered correct.